# How do I find my files from my Windows account?

Tags: windows, linux-mint

I've just installed Linux Mint 16 (Cinnamon) on my laptop from disc, and I cannot find my files ANYWHERE, and I'm new totally to Linux so, rookie alert... Also, it does not allow me to choose between Linux and Windows on start-up... Have I completely ballsed it up or is there a solution to this?

Comment: Please read the [about] page

Comment: Depends on how you installed it. Linux Mint is off-topic here however. Try on [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

First type `su` and type password of root to get authorized. Then type `fdisk -l` to get the partition table.

For me it gives:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     3074047     1536000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         3074048    86960127    41943040    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        86960128   170481663    41760768    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       170483710   564758527   197137409    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       170483712   183066623     6291456   82  Linux swap
/dev/sda6       183068672   187262975     2097152   83  Linux
```

Now I know that my windows partition is on /dev/sda2 as I remember and `fdisk` said that it is NTFS partition.

Another Important thing I should know is that if the /dev/sda2 had mounted or not. And if mounted, where?

The file `/etc/fstab` tells me this. so `cat /etc/fstab` command. for me it gives this:

```
/dev/sda5        swap             swap        defaults         0   0
/dev/sda8        /                ext4        defaults         1   1
/dev/sda6        /boot            ext4        defaults         1   2
/dev/sda7        /home            ext4        defaults         1   2
/dev/sda9        /friend          ext4        defaults         1   2
/dev/sda2        /ms7             ntfs-3g     fmask=133,dmask=022 1   0
```

Ok, as you see, /dev/sda2 is mounted on /ms7. I can access my files of windows drive (or /dev/sda2) from directory `/ms7`.

But, If the windows partition is not listed here, You can mount it yourself to any directory you want, for example a good temporary  directory is (/mnt/tmp). To mount your windows partition use (for me is /dev/sda2):

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/tmp
```

Now you can access your files from `/mnt/tmp` directory.